# How can I create hierachial ENUM Types in java

Tags: java, enums

How can I support the data structure of a tree like type using Java `Enumeration`

For e.g. `Type` and its `subTypes` and their `subTypes` in one `Enum`

This would allow to just iterate the type in the code and derive its parent and so on, to check the origin and position of a particular type in the `Type` tree.

Comment: if anyone has a better solution than first answer please post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in this great link after hours of search

[Enum Hierachy](http://java.dzone.com/articles/enum-tricks-hierarchical-data) Excerpt from the link below

```
 public enum OsType {
    OS(null),
        Windows(OS),
            WindowsNT(Windows),
                WindowsNTWorkstation(WindowsNT),
                WindowsNTServer(WindowsNT),
            Windows2000(Windows),
                Windows2000Server(Windows2000),
                Windows2000Workstation(Windows2000),
            WindowsXp(Windows),
            WindowsVista(Windows),
            Windows7(Windows),
            Windows95(Windows),
            Windows98(Windows),
        Unix(OS) {
                @Override
                public boolean supportsXWindows() {
                    return true;
                }
            },
            Linux(Unix),
            AIX(Unix),
            HpUx(Unix),
            SunOs(Unix),
    ;
    private OsType parent = null;

    private OsType(OsType parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

This can be further extended by providing value for the look-up

like

```
 public enum OsType {
    OS(null,null),
        Windows(OS,"Win"),
            WindowsNT(Windows,"WinNT"),
                WindowsNTWorkstation(WindowsNT,"WinNTWorkStation")
....
private OsType parent = null;
private String desc = null;

private OsType(OsType parent,String desc) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.desc   = desc;
}
```

Comment: You should post information from the link and summarize it in your answer. It would prevent the loss of information in case the link die.